# Bukkit Plugin: How to stop timer using command

Tags: java, bukkit

So basically I have

```
timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(new TimerTask() {
    public void run() {
    }
}
```

that runs when the command "play" is sent by a player, and I want to stop and reset the timer when a player sends the command "cancel". How can I do this?

Answer (score 1):

By using Bukkit's scheduler API, it's better.

Firstly, start your server:

```
BukkitTask task = Bukkit.getScheduler().runTaskTimer(myPlugin, () -> {
   // do something
}, 20, 20);
```

Then, with the task variable, you can cancel it:

```
task.cancel();
```

Finally, the next time, you will be able to just create a new timer that will replace the task variable.

Answer (score 0):

You could create a static [Timer](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Timer.html) object and cancel it in your cancel command class.

/play (PlayCommand)

```
public static Timer timer = null;


timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(new TimerTask() {
   public void run() {
      //Run your Timer code
   }
}
```

/cancel (CancelCommand)

```
PlayCommand.timer.cancel();
```

Comment: You'll need to replay "PlayCommand" with the class name of the class that the timer object is in.